# Add logic to single field for custom object on lightning edit page

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, page-layout

I currently have a visualforce page which overrides the edit page for a custom Salesforce object.

The effect of the page is to replace an input for a particular field with a custom picklist, with its values generated as the page is loaded in a custom controller.

We have switched to lighting and I would like to have the same functionality but can't figure out how to implement it.

Do I need to create an entire lightning component for the edit page or is there another way to have custom functionality for just a single field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component just for the single field, you'd just have to add it to a custom Record Page. You wouldn't need to recreate the entire edit page. You'll want to read more about it in [Configure Components for Lightning Experience Record Pages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_record_home.htm#!). Simply create the component, edit the record page to include the new component, and activate it as the default page for your object.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is it possible to insert that item within the page layout beside the other custom fields? As far as I can see lightning components can only be inserted above or below the page layout defined from the object setup.

Comment: @PatrickWard No, it doesn't work like Visualforce does. It would need to be in a separate area, or you would end up having to write an entire edit page.